# pros/cons using different implementations for different environments

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I know dependency injection allows it but would you ever want to inject different implementations for different testing environments?  I.e use implementationA for in sprint testing and implementationB for regression? (Say the implementation change was for a data repository.)

I was having a conversation about this
and to me it sounds dangerous as the integrity of the package would be comprised if the implementation changed depending on what environment it is.

I've worked with platforms that have different configuration but not actual code implementation being switched.

Any thoughts/ possible pro and cons?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DI container will make it much easier to intercept or decorate dependencies. This allows you to add cross-cutting concerns (such as decorators that measure performance) without changing the actual behavior of the system. This allows you to plug-in these kinds of aspects when running the acceptance test environment or when automatically run the integration test suite. Since you're not replacing certain dependencies, but merely 'enhance' them, you are not changing the behavior of the system and the risk is relatively low.